# UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.namespace.com/RTS", local:"container")

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, mapping

I am trying to map my xml to java classes.
Xml comes from a third-party service. The structure is the same, but there may be a different prefix or namespace. XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xdms:container xmlns:xdms="http://www.namespace.com/RTS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xdms:uid="FHGHDFGDFJKGDFHG" xdms:version="3.2">
    <xdms:requisites>
        <xdms:documentKind>letter</xdms:documentKind>
        <xdms:classification>main</xdms:classification>
        <xdms:annotation>unknown</xdms:annotation>
    </xdms:requisites>
</>
```

My classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "container")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Container {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "requisites")
    private Requisites requisites;

    public Container() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Container{" +
                "requisites=" + requisites +
                '}';
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "requisites")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Requisites implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String documentKind;
    private String classification;
    private String annotation;

    public Requisites() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Requisites{" +
                "documentKind='" + documentKind + '\'' +
                ", classfication='" + classification + '\'' +
                ", annotation='" + annotation + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the main class in which I run parsing:

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    File xmlFile = new File("test.xml");
    try
    {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Container cont = (Container) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);

        System.out.println(cont);
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I get the error:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://www.namespace.com/RTS", local:"container"). Expected
>   elements are <{}container>,<{}requisites>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)

**UPD:**
I added nameSpace, the error is gone. But the fields of my objects are not filled with information. They are empty, although in xml they are filled with information

> Container{requisites=Requisites{documentKind='null',
>   classfication='null', annotation='null'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the namespace in your jaxb class

Something like that:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "container", namespace = "http://www.namespace.com/RTS")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Container {

    @XmlElement(name = "requisites", namespace="http://www.namespace.com/RTS")
    private Requisites requisites;

}
```

you might need to add namespace to every element in `Requisites` as well.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "requisites")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Requisites implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "documentKind", namespace="http://www.namespace.com/RTS")
    private String documentKind;
    @XmlElement(name = "classification", namespace="http://www.namespace.com/RTS")
    private String classification;
    @XmlElement(name = "annotation", namespace="http://www.namespace.com/RTS")
    private String annotation;
```

Comment: I added nameSpace, the error is gone. But the fields of my objects are not filled with information. They are empty, although in xml they are filled with information. 

`Container{requisites=Requisites{documentKind='null', classfication='null', annotation='null'}}`

Comment: @maksim2112 add the namespace to the elements of requisites as well. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the namespace attribute in the @XmlRootElement as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="container", namespace="http://www.namespace.com/RTS")
```

In case, if it still throws the same error, you also have to specify the namespace attribute in your @XmlElement:

```
@XmlElement(name="requisites", namespace="http://www.namespace.com/RTS")
```

Your each attribute inside the Requisites tag should also contain the namespace within its @XmlElement annotation.