# Jaxb java set namespace to all elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a Java class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "a")
public class a {
    @XmlElementWrapper
    public Component[] components;

    public String content;
}
```

And an XML file: `test.xml` and XSD file which is generated using the `JAXBContext::generateSchema` method.

An example XML file:

```
<a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://example.com"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com file://...schema.xsd">
</a>
```

If I want to unmarshal it, I need to add namespace = "http://example.com" to all elements.

Otherwise, I will get a `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060432/unmarshalexception-unexpected-element-urihttp-www-namespace-com-rts-loca).

However, If I have a lot of classes in many different packages, or some fields that are annotated with `@XmlElements` has a lot of `@XmlElement` children.

I need to copy and paste `namespace = "http://example.com"` uncountable times, it is dumb and meaningless. Are there some methods that allow me to only type the namespace once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add file: package-info.java to your package.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = 
"http://webservices.com/myws",
   xmlns = { 
       @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "ws", 
       namespaceURI="http://webservices.com/myws")
   } 
)
package mypackage;
```

Comment: What if I have many packages?

Comment: You must add it to each one, but its still better than editing each class :)